# Show that $S^{\perp \perp} \equiv (S^\perp)^\perp$ is the closure of $S$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $S$ is a (not neccessarily closed) subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Show that $S^{\perp \perp} \equiv (S^\perp)^\perp$ is the closure of $S$.

I know that if $X\in H$, that $X^\perp$ is a closed subspace, but not really sure where to go from there?

Comment: So how is $S^{\perp}$ related to $S$?

Comment: $S^\perp$ is the set of all vectors $y$ such that $x\perp y$ (or $<x,y>=0$) for all $x\in S$.

Comment: Just so. So what can you say about $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$?

Comment: @user3784030 [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352469/orthogonal-complement-of-a-hilbert-space) can be helpful.

Comment: So then $(S^\perp )^\perp$ would be the set of all $z\in S^\perp$ such that $z\perp y \implies <z,y>=0$ and as $<z,y>=<x,y>$ then $z=x$?

Comment: You need to know some facts about Hilbert Space; otherwise I'm afraid the answer to your question is going to involve too much. Do you know that $L\oplus L^{\perp}=X$ if $L$ is a closed linear subspace of the Hilbert space $X$? Or, equivalently, do you know that every orthonormal subset of $X$ can be completed to an orthonormal basis?

Comment: See also: [How can I show $U^{\bot \bot}\subseteq \overline{U}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108943/how-can-i-show-u-bot-bot-subseteq-overlineu)