# How can I show $U^{\bot \bot}\subseteq \overline{U}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $U$ a subspace. Let $U^{\bot}$ denote its orthogonal complement.

I had no trouble showing $\overline{U}\subseteq U^{\bot\bot}$. But now I'm stuck for $\supseteq$.

> Please could someone help me finish this argument?

This is what I am trying to do:

Let $x \in U^{\bot \bot}$. The goal is to construct a sequence $u_n\in U$ such that $u_n \to x$.

Since $\overline{U} \subset U^{\bot \bot}$ either $x\in \overline{U}$ or $x \notin \overline{U}$. If $x \in \overline{U}$ then we're done. If $x \notin \overline{U}$ I don't know what I can do.

Comment: This post seems closely related: [Orthogonal complement of a Hilbert Space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352469/orthogonal-complement-of-a-hilbert-space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: If $x\not\in \overline{U}$, then by [Hilbert projection theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) we have $x=y+z$ with $y\in \overline{U}$ and $0\ne z\perp \overline{U}$.

Since $z\ne 0$ one has 
$$ \langle x,z\rangle=\langle y+z,z\rangle=\| z\|^2\ne 0. $$
Hence $z\in U^\perp$ does not annihilate $x$ and therefore $x\not\in U^{\perp\perp}$.

Comment: Hilbert projection theorem seems to be shooting the pigeon with a canon. Is there a way to prove it from first principles? Otherwise I will instead have to prove Hilbert projection theorem first... and that seems more difficult than the problem at hand.

Comment: @student Somehow you have to show that in the case $x\not\in \overline{U}$ there exists $0\ne z\in U^\perp$ such that $\langle x,z\rangle \ne 0$ and therefore $x\not\in U^{\perp\perp}$. If you will be able to see $\overline{U}=U^{\perp\perp}$ in some different way, then from this you can deduce Hilbert projection theorem, at least partially, I guess.

Comment: How do you get the result you state in the answer from the Hilbert projection theorem?

Comment: From the theorem we get a $y \in \overline{U}$ such that $\|x-y\|$ is minimal. It's not clear why $z = x-y$ should be orthogonal to $\overline{U}$.

Comment: I see. If it minimizes it can't be non-orthogonal?

Comment: How to finish the argument? We have to show that $\langle x, u\rangle = 0$ for $u \in U^\bot$. But 
$$ \langle y + z, u\rangle = \langle z,u \rangle$$
and I  don't see why that should be zero...

Comment: @student I have extended the answer. However I guess that you have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For closed subspaces:
$$Z=\overline{Z}\implies\mathcal{H}=Z\oplus_\perp Z^\perp$$

For orthogonal decompositions:
$$\mathcal{H}=Z\oplus_\perp Z'\implies Z'=Z^\perp$$

Taking both together one gets:
$$\overline{U}=\left(\overline{U}^\perp\right)^\perp=U^{\perp\perp}$$
*(This works even for the closure on the span of plain sets.)*

Comment: This requires the Hilbert projection theorem mentioned in the previous answer.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Yep, I know; but I think it is important to mention the order of reasoning here. *(Especially since the projection theorem does only half of the story.)*