# Showing $(U^{\perp \perp})^{\perp \perp} = U^{\perp \perp}$ where $U$ is an infinite dimensional subspace of an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I would like to show that $(U^{\perp \perp})^{\perp \perp} = U^{\perp \perp}$. I know that if $U$ is a finite dimensional subspace then the equality holds as $U^{\perp \perp} = U$. However I'm not sure how to prove the case in which $U$ is infinite dimensional, specifically, I can't see how $(U^{\perp \perp})^{\perp \perp} \subset U^{\perp \perp}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A subspace of what?

Comment: This may be relevant. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352469/orthogonal-complement-of-a-hilbert-space

Comment: @martini It's a subspace of an inner product space, sorry I forgot to include that.

Comment: As pointed out by @TheHype, separable Hilbert spaces seem the paradigmatic example of what you're asking about, especially now that you've added "inner product space".

Comment: We have in general, that $U^{\perp \perp} = \overline{U}$ (where the overline means the closure). Thus, we get $$ (U^{\perp \perp})^{\perp \perp} = (\overline{U})^{\perp \perp} = \overline{(\overline{U})} = \overline{U} = U^{\perp \perp}. $$ Here we used that the closure of the closure is again the closure.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you! I'm also curious if there is any way to prove this without using topology?

Comment: I must admit that I do not know whether it is possible to show it without topology. If I was forced to guess, I would say it should be possible to do so. Probably it would be a bit messy as there are many duals floating around.